# Creating a fake object.method() "from scratch" in sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

#### tl;dr

How do you create an object.method() "from scratch" in sinon?

#### the context

For example, I have a family of `Parser` classes where each implements a `#parse(text)` method and returns a `ParseTree` object or returns `null`.

I am doing unit testing where I'm *not* testing `Parser` objects themselves (they are tested elsewhere) but I need an testable object that responds to `#parse()`.   I could instantiate and stub a real Parser, but that drags needless code into this part of the test.

#### the question

I'm pretty sure this is easy using sinon's spy(), stub() and/or mock() api's, so: how do I create a testable object that:

- responds to the parse() method
- verifies that it is called once
- returns an arbitrary object that I specify?

#### what I've tried

The following contrived example fails in the call to `sinon.stub()` because a `sinon.spy()` object cannot be stubbed with a `parse` method.  (This example should also verify that `fake_parser.parse()` was called once with `test_text`, but it doesn't):

```
var test_text = 'any text'
var fake_parse_tree = sinon.spy()
var fake_parser = sinon.stub(sinon.spy(), 'parse').returns(fake_parse_tree)

expect(fake_parser.parse(test_text)).to.equal(fake_parse_tree)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a dummy `Parser` object and stub the `parse()` method of it. The details will depend on how you're creating your Parsers, but something like:

```
var Parser = {
    parse: function() { }
};

var parseStub = sinon.stub(Parser, 'parse');
parseStub.returns(fake_parse_tree);

// execute code that invokes the parser

parseStub.callCount.should.equal(1);
parseStub.alwaysCalledWithExactly(test_text).should.be.true();
```

Comment: Ah!  A key point is that `sinon.stub(obj, method)` returns the stubbed METHOD, not the object.  I was getting confused because I was trying to pass parseStub to my code, which expected a parser.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

@Stephen Thomas [gave the right answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30199011/558639).  For future reference, here's what I finally did.  The 'aha' is that `sinon.stub(object, 'method')` returns the stubbed *method*, not the object.

Because this is javascript (and methods are first-class objects) returning the method makes perfect sense:

```
var test_text = 'any text';
var parse_tree = sinon.spy(); // could be any object
var proxy_parser = { parseText: function() { } };
var stubbed_method = sinon.stub(proxy_parser, 'parseText').returns(parse_tree)

// App specific tests not shown here:
// ...pass proxy_parser to a function that calls proxy_parser.parseText()
// ...verify that the function returned the parse_tree

expect(stubbed_method.callCount).to.equal(1)
expect(stubbed_method.alwaysCalledWithExactly(test_text)).to.be.true
```